# DOM find ID returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting undefined error whenever i click body elements. not sure where's the issue..

```
$('body').on('click',function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: Why to set `body` an id ?

Comment: where ever we click on any page if "id" is available it should alert. by finding the id, need to add google analytic code

Comment: `whenever i click body elements` Because there is only one `body` element per document context,  I guess you mean body descendants: `$('body').on('click',function(e) {console.log(e.target.id);});`  but this would be cleaner for sure: `$('body').on('click', '[id]', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});`

Comment: [**It is working**](http://jsfiddle.net/6z2qbzs8/)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery event callbacks `this` context is always equal to the object on which you assign your event. For `$('body').on('click'` callback `this` will always be a `body` DOM element, wherever a user clicked.

If you want to get the top most clicked element, you need to access event's `target` property:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.target.id); // it is "" if no id presented
});
```

Check this snippet out:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e)
{ 
  $("#result").text(e.target.id === "" ? "No ID" : e.target.id);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background-color: red;" id="red"></div>
<div style="background-color: green;" id="green"></div>
<div style="background-color: blue;" id="blue"></div>
<div style="background-color: black;" id="black"></div>
<div style="background-color: yellow;"></div>

<br/><span id="result"></span>
```